# Push project to Heroku has been rejected if I change Python version

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

I have a Python Scrapy project on heroku using Python 2. I still can push to Heroku if I have some code update.

Now I want to update python version to Python 3.

It looks like Heroku support Python 3: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1442

So I update my `runtime.txt` file from `python-2.7.15` to `python-3.7.0`

And my `requirements.txt` is:

```
pymongo==3.5.1
Scrapy==1.4.0
scrapyd==1.0.1
scrapy-heroku==0.7.1
cffi==1.6.0
requests==2.5.3
```

And then type `git push heroku master`, here is the terminal's information:

```
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 740 bytes | 740.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 6), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Found python-2.7.15, removing
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.0
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting pymongo==3.5.1
remote:          Downloading pymongo-3.5.1.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting Scrapy==1.4.0
remote:          Downloading Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (248 kB)
remote:        Collecting scrapyd==1.0.1
remote:          Downloading scrapyd-1.0.1.tar.gz (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting scrapy-heroku==0.7.1
remote:          Downloading scrapy-heroku-0.7.1.tar.gz (5.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.6.0
remote:          Downloading cffi-1.6.0.tar.gz (397 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.5.3
remote:          Downloading requests-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (468 kB)
remote:        Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0
remote:          Downloading Twisted-19.10.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting cssselect>=0.9
remote:          Downloading cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting parsel>=1.1
remote:          Downloading parsel-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting w3lib>=1.17.0
remote:          Downloading w3lib-1.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyOpenSSL
remote:          Downloading pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        Collecting service-identity
remote:          Downloading service_identity-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5
remote:          Downloading PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz (34 kB)
remote:        Collecting lxml
remote:          Downloading lxml-4.5.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting six>=1.5.2
remote:          Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting queuelib
remote:          Downloading queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting distribute
remote:          Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/pip-egg-info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/
remote:            Complete output (15 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command.install import install
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command import install_scripts
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-bb2wfsg5/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
remote:                register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
remote:            AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myproject.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myproject.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myproject.git'
```

If my project python's version still 2.7.15 push will work.

I don't know why I get rejected when I change it to 3.7.0, how do I update my project to Python 3 on Heroku?

When change `requests==2.23.0`

The output is:

```
Enumerating objects: 27, done.
Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 1.59 KiB | 812.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 14), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.6
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Found python-2.7.15, removing
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.0
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting pymongo==3.5.1
remote:          Downloading pymongo-3.5.1.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting Scrapy==1.4.0
remote:          Downloading Scrapy-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (248 kB)
remote:        Collecting scrapyd==1.0.1
remote:          Downloading scrapyd-1.0.1.tar.gz (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting scrapy-heroku==0.7.1
remote:          Downloading scrapy-heroku-0.7.1.tar.gz (5.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.6.0
remote:          Downloading cffi-1.6.0.tar.gz (397 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.23.0
remote:          Downloading requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        Collecting queuelib
remote:          Downloading queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting cssselect>=0.9
remote:          Downloading cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting service-identity
remote:          Downloading service_identity-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting w3lib>=1.17.0
remote:          Downloading w3lib-1.21.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
remote:        Collecting six>=1.5.2
remote:          Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyOpenSSL
remote:          Downloading pyOpenSSL-19.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        Collecting parsel>=1.1
remote:          Downloading parsel-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0
remote:          Downloading Twisted-19.10.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting lxml
remote:          Downloading lxml-4.5.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5
remote:          Downloading PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz (34 kB)
remote:        Collecting distribute
remote:          Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/pip-egg-info
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/
remote:            Complete output (15 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command.install import install
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command import install_scripts
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-60s4l_1v/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
remote:                register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
remote:            AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myproject.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myproject.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myproject.git'
```

Comment: What's the `...other info`? That's where the useful information is.

Comment: Yes, your right, I had pated all of the info, take a look plz.

Comment: Sorry for late, I try `purging your build cache` is not working. I try to use `installing pipdeptree` and deep into it to find what is going on. I will report it recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're (indirectly) depending on [`distribute`](https://pypi.org/project/distribute/), which is a

> legacy package [providing a] simple compatibility layer that installs Setuptools 0.7+

It isn't building properly due to

```
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

which makes sense since `importlib._bootstrap` doesn't contain a `SourceFileLoader` class in Python 3.7.

`distribute`'s PyPI page says it's compatible with Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3.

It is being pulled in by [an old version of `requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.5.3/). Update your `requirements.txt` to use a newer version: [the latest is currently 2.23.0](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

It's always a good idea to try installing in a clean local virtual environment from your `requirements.txt` to make sure you have a good configuration after a major upgrade, and going from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 definitely counts as a major upgrade.

Once you're confident in the contents of your `requirements.txt`, commit it and redeploy.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so I have downgrade my requests from `requests==2.5.3` to `requests==2.23.0` ?   I redeploy the project still get `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'` from Heroku.  Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: That's a significant _upgrade_, not a downgrade. `requests` 2.5.3 came out five years ago. Please edit the new build output into your question.

Comment: Thanks again, I had updated the new output when I set `requests==2.23.0`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when I checked on my phone this morning. You probably have a cached dependency that's too old. Try [purging your build cache](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache). If that doesn't do it we're going to have to dig deeper. Try installing [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) and using it locally to find anything that depends on `distribute`. Eliminate or upgrade anything you find, depending on what it is.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion, to see what will happen next step.

Comment: You're right, I just try to remove some dependencies, the problem comes from `scrapy-heroku==0.7.1`, if I remove it, push project to heroku is working. But it looks like auto scrapy from heroku will won't work...

Any way, very thanks for your help bro.